# How can i display the result of the dynamic soql query

Tags: soql

I have dynamic soql result in my apex code. The fields used for dynamic soql also been selected dynamically. I want to display the result on my VF page with the field name and value in it. My apex dynamic soql result :

> (Contact:{Email=agreen@uog.com, AccountId=001bWzAAI, Id=00302yAAG, LastName=Green}, Contact:{Email=spavlova@uog.com, AccountId=0011lbWzAAI, Id=0035QC2oAAG, LastName=Pavlova}, Contact:{Email=lboyle@uog.com, AccountId=000lbWzAAI, Id=005QC2pAAG, LastName=Boyle}, Contact:{Email=asong@uog.com, AccountId=0001lbWzAAI, Id=000015tAAG, LastName=Song})

I want to display this result on my VF page. All the fields and object where condition is generated from dynamic soql query. 
my apex dynamic query:

```
 public void searchResult(){

    //queryBuilder = '';
    string value;
    queryWhereCondition = '';
    system.debug('Wrapper class on search ' + wcls);

    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Field_Set_Category__c fsc_baseObj = [SELECT Base_object__c, Search_Display__c FROM Field_Set_Category__c WHERE Id = :myid];

    //for(integer i =0; fsc_baseObj.size()){
       // soqlfields= soqlfields + 
    //}

    if(fsc_baseObj.Search_Display__c  != null && fsc_baseObj.Search_Display__c  != '')
        queryBuilder = 'SELECT Id, '+ fsc_baseObj.Search_Display__c +' FROM '+fsc_baseObj.Base_object__c+' Where';
    else
        queryBuilder = 'SELECT Id FROM '+fsc_baseObj.Base_object__c+' Where';

    //Schema.SObjectType objectName = schemaMap.get(fsc_baseObj.Base_object__c);

    Schema.sObjectType parentType = schemaMap.get(fsc_baseObj.Base_object__c);
    //Schema.sObjectType parentType = schemaMap.get('Account'); 
    List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldList = parentType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values();

    String Referenceobj;

    for(SObjectField fieldLs : fieldList){ 
       system.debug('Looping through field list ' + fieldLs);
       if(string.valueof(fieldLs.getDescribe().getType()) == 'REFERENCE'){

            system.debug('The details about all the fields ' + fieldLs.getDescribe());
            system.debug('To which object is reference ' + (fieldLs.getDescribe()).getReferenceTo() );

            Referenceobj = String.valueof((fieldLs.getDescribe()).getReferenceTo());
            if(Referenceobj.contains(')')){
                Referenceobj = Referenceobj.replace(')', '');                   
            }
            if(Referenceobj.contains('(')){
                Referenceobj = Referenceobj.replace('(', '');        
            }

            querymaker.put(Referenceobj, String.valueof(fieldLs.getDescribe().getRelationshipName()));
       }
    }


    for(wrapperClass wap: wcls){

        system.debug('Index of ' + string.valueof(wap.objectName).indexOf(':', 0));
        system.debug('object name in wrapper class ' + wap.objectName);

        objectName = string.valueof(wap.objectName).substring(0, string.valueof(wap.objectName).indexOf(':', 0));
        system.debug('Name of the object ' + objectName );


        if(querymaker.containsKey(objectName)){
            system.debug('Yes the value conatins ' + querymaker.get(objectName) );
            //system.debug('' + querymaker.get(objectName) );

             fieldNameValue = string.valueof(wap.objectName);

             system.debug('field Name Value ' + fieldNameValue );

             if(fieldNameValue.contains(objectName))
                fieldNameValue = fieldNameValue.replace(objectName,querymaker.get(objectName));
             if(fieldNameValue.contains(':'))
                fieldNameValue = fieldNameValue.replace(':','.');
             if(fieldNameValue.contains('{'))
                fieldNameValue = fieldNameValue.replace('{','');
             if(fieldNameValue.contains('}'))
                fieldNameValue = fieldNameValue.replace('}','');

            if(fieldNameValue.length() != (fieldNameValue.indexOf('.') + 1) ){

                system.debug('Checking is not null ' + fieldNameValue.substring(fieldNameValue.indexOf('=', 0)+1, fieldNameValue.length()));

                if( fieldNameValue.substring(fieldNameValue.indexOf('=', 0)+1, fieldNameValue.length()) != 'null'){

                    fieldName = fieldNameValue.substring(fieldNameValue.indexOf('.', 0)+1, fieldNameValue.indexOf('=', fieldNameValue.indexOf('.', 0)));   
                    system.debug('name of the field ' + fieldName);    

                    Schema.sObjectType objsNameType = schemaMap.get(objectName); 
                    List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldTypList = objsNameType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values();

                    for(SObjectField fieldLsTyp: fieldTypList){
                        if(string.valueof(fieldLsTyp) == fieldName){

                        if(string.valueof(fieldLsTyp.getDescribe().getType()) == 'ID' || string.valueof(fieldLsTyp.getDescribe().getType()) == 'STRING' ||
                            string.valueof(fieldLsTyp.getDescribe().getType()) == 'PICKLIST' || string.valueof(fieldLsTyp.getDescribe().getType()) == 'PHONE'){

                            value = fieldNameValue.substring(fieldNameValue.indexOf('=', 0)+1, fieldNameValue.length());
                            system.debug('value for search ' + value);

                            fieldNameValue = fieldNameValue.replace(value, '\''+value +'\'');
                            system.debug('Repaced value for search ' + fieldNameValue);

                            if(fieldNameValue.contains('MasterRecord')){
                                fieldNameValue = fieldNameValue.replace('MasterRecord', objectName);
                            }
                            queryWhereCondition = queryWhereCondition + ' ' +fieldNameValue +' AND';
                        }
                        else{
                            if(string.valueof(fieldLsTyp.getDescribe().getType()) == 'INTEGER' ){

                                if(fieldNameValue.contains('MasterRecord')){
                                    fieldNameValue = fieldNameValue.replace('MasterRecord', objectName);
                                }

                                queryWhereCondition = queryWhereCondition + ' ' +fieldNameValue +' AND';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }                   
                system.debug('query Builder after adding ' + queryWhereCondition );

            }
            }

        }

    }   
    queryWhereCondition = queryWhereCondition.substring(0, queryWhereCondition.lastIndexOf('AND'));         
    system.debug('query Where Condition ' + queryWhereCondition );

    queryBuilder = queryBuilder +' '+ queryWhereCondition;  
    system.debug('query Builder after adding add fields for SOQL ' + queryBuilder );

    //if(queryBuilder.contains('MasterRecord')){
        //queryBuilder.replaceAll('MasterRecord', objectName);
    //}

    soqlResult = new list<sObject>();
    soqlResult = Database.query(queryBuilder);
    system.debug('Dynamic soql result ' + soqlResult );
```

Can anyone guide me what are the different ways to display the fields on my VF page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a public property to your controller populated with a list of the field names (called `fields` below) that you want to display (which could be all the values in your `fieldList`) and then you can use this Visualforce to present the table:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable var="item" value="{!soqlResult}">
    <apex:repeat var="f" value="{!fields}">
        <apex:column value="{!item[f]}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```